# Protocol Upgrade Mechanism in okHttp Interceptors

Tags: java, http, okhttp, interceptor

I need to upgrade my request from being served by HTTP1.1 to HTTP/2.
This is so far what I have tried.

```
public class H2cUpgradeRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(H2cUpgradeRequestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Request upgradeRequest = request.newBuilder().addHeader("Connection", "Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings")
                .addHeader("Upgrade", "h2c").addHeader("HTTP2-Settings", "AAMAAABkAARAAAAAAAIAAAAA").build();
        Response upgradeResponse = chain.proceed(upgradeRequest);
        if (upgradeResponse != null && upgradeResponse.code() == HttpStatus.SC_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS) {
            logger.debug("Switching Protocols success"); // Success. Got 101 in reply.
        }
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if (response.protocol() == Protocol.HTTP_2) { // This is returning HTTP1.1 as protocol
            logger.debug("Used upgraded h2c protocol");
        }
        return response;

    }

}
```

My server has h2c enabled. I am also receiving 101 Switching Protocols in my first `chain.proceed()` call. But the next `proceed()` always gives me HTTP1.1 as protocol even if switching protocols is successful. Is it right right way of achieving protocol upgrade? And, if yes, how can I make sure it uses HTTP2 after switching protocol is successful?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this since, as per the [docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.7)

I need not send the request again.

> If the Upgrade header field is received in a GET request and the
> server decides to switch protocols, it first responds with a 101
> (Switching Protocols) message in HTTP/1.1 and then immediately follows
> that with the new protocol's equivalent of a response to a GET on the
> target resource. This allows a connection to be upgraded to protocols
> with the same semantics as HTTP without the latency cost of an
> additional round trip.

Following back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170331/how-to-read-body-following-an-101-response-code)